# select order by issue

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data

I'm created the BOM table as follows:

```
i_rownum i_level segment parent
　　1　　　0　　　A1　　　-
　　2　　　1　　　B1　　　A1
　　3　　　1　　　B2　　　A1
　　4　　　1　　　B3　　　A1
　　5　　　1　　　B4　　　A1
　　6　　　2　　　C1　　　B1
　　7　　　2　　　C2　　　B2
　　8　　　2　　　C3　　　B3
　　9　　　3　　　D1　　　C3
　　10　　 3 　　 D2　　　C3
```

A1 is a parent of B1,B2,B3,B4; B1 is a parent of C1; B2 is a parent of C2;....

However, to understand level and subsegment clearly, what I hope to see is:

```
i_rownum i_level segment parent
　　1　　　0　　　A1　　　-
　　2　　　1　　　B1　　　A1
　　3　　　2　　　C1　　　B1
　　4　　　1　　　B2　　　A1
　　5　　　2　　　C2　　　B2
　　6　　　1　　　B3　　　A1
　　7　　　2　　　C3　　　B3
　　8　　　3　　　D1　　　C3
　　9　　　3　　　D2　　　C3
　　10　　 1　　  B4  　　A1
```

I'm not sure that applying order by could solve this issue. Could you help? Many thanks!

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images (or links to images.)

Comment: Updated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
SELECT segment, parent, level
  FROM <TABLE>
 START WITH PARENT = '-'
 CONNECT BY PARENT = PRIOR segment
```

This is just the typical hierarchical query and should give you exactly what you want. Furthermore as you can see, I am using the `LEVEL` keyword in the query. You do not need to save this information in the table as Oracle calculates the level itself in the query...

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Oracle 11g or higher, you can try to use [Recursive Subquery Factoring](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#BABCDJDB). 
This kind of query is good for traversing hierarchical structures like yours. Among other things it gives you a possibility to traverse the hierarchy in [depth-first search order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) which is apparently what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT i_rownum, i_level, segment, parent,level 
FROM bom start with parent is null connect by
parent = prior segment;
```

I think this should work